# Libgdx touchUp on image not working

Tags: android, libgdx

I have an image that I want to register touch such that it only activates whenever user lifts their finger off the screen after touching(provided its stil in the same region)..not immediately it's clicked. I am trying to use TouchUp like the documentation says but to no avail

```
large_jackpot.addListener(new InputListener() {

        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            Gdx.app.log("Example", "touch started at (" + x + ", " + y + ")");

            return true;
        }

        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            Gdx.app.log("Example", "touch done at (" + x + ", " + y + ")");

            app.setScreen(app.loadingScreen);
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your listener is alright. I guess you problem is in event system. It is possible that something above Image class is capturing *touchUp* event or you did not set *InputProcessor*. This code works as expected on libGDX generated project:

```
stage = new Stage();
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
image = new Image(img);
image.addListener(new InputListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        Gdx.app.log("Image","touchDown");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        Gdx.app.log("Image","touchUp");
    }
});
stage.addActor(image);
```

If it does not help you please provide more code.